# Executing a shell script with parameters through python always takes the default values when executing the shell script

Tags: python, shell, subprocess, sh

My python is supposed to execute the /home/file.sh with five parameters as shown below. However, everytime I execute my python script it ignores the parameters and the shell script executes with default values. I have also tried turning the shell to False but no success. Any ideas ? Thank you in advance!

```
var1='-t'
var2='m'
var3='20130105'
var4='-f'
var5='test.txt'

process=subprocess.Popen(['/home/file.sh', str(var1), str(var2), str(var3), str(var4), str(var5)],shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
process.wait()
lists=process.communicate()[0]
```

I have tried the following but it again use the default parameters

```
process=subprocess.Popen(['/home/file.sh  -t m 20140105 -f test.txt')],shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Comment: Also, note that you don't have to expicitly `wait`, as `communicate` implies waiting for the process to exit.

Answer (score 0):

Try like so:

```
process=subprocess.Popen('/home/file.sh -t m 20140105 -f test.txt', shell=True, ...)
```

without worrying about passing a list for your command.

Comment: And how are you able to tell that `file.sh` is doing the wrong thing?  What is the output of `file.sh` vs. the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Either you use an argument list and set `shell=False`, e.g.

```
process=subprocess.Popen(["./test.sh","a","b","c"], shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
print process.communicate()[0]
```

or you can use a string argument and let the shell parse it by setting `shell=True`, e.g.

```
process=subprocess.Popen("./test.sh a b c", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
print process.communicate()[0]
```

but you can not send a list when using `shell=True`.

Both will output

```
0: ./test.sh
1: a
2: b
3: c
```

if test.sh is an executable file with the following contents:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo 0: $0
echo 1: $1
echo 2: $2
echo 3: $3
```

Ususally, I prefer using `shell=False` to avoid having to escape the argument strings (it's trickier than it should be to get this right). Using the shell has some advantages though, such as expansion of paths, being able to use shell internals and so on.

Comment: Are you sure that your script is working properly? Can you run this command-line from a regular shell?

Comment: Hi, yes it works from the command..I'm double checking the script if there's a way to modify it to use the $1, $2, ... directly. I'll keep you updated Thanks!